# Is there any specific steps for configuring protobuf in QNX?

Tags: gcc, vmware, qnx

We have tried to configure using ./configure command.
An error is like no c++11 compiler support.
We are following the steps ie mentioned in some blog.
We want to know like is there any other specific steps for this?

Comment: there is no way to know if there are any other steps because you did not say what steps you did

Comment: We have followed the steps mentioned in this link http://programmersought.com/article/78321808787/

Comment: Protobuf team made C++11 support as mandatory from v3.6.x onwards. You can compile Protobuf v3.5.x or below without C++11 support. Refer: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/2780#issuecomment-352557942

Answer (score 0):

```
./autogen.sh

./configure 
    -disable-shared 
    CFLAGS='-fPIC' 
    CXXFLAGS='-fPIC' 
    --host=aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.0.0  # or x86_64-pc-nto-qnx7.0.0
    CC=aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.0.0-gcc 
    CXX=aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.0.0-g++ 
    --prefix='path-to-install/protobuf' 
    --with-protoc='path-to-local-installed/protobuf/bin/protoc' 
    CPPFLAGS='-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500'

make
make install
```